# Using a CDN other than Amazon's with S3 as my main file storage

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, cdn

I am running a `django` app on `heroku`. I am using `Amazon S3` to store static and media assets. I want to speed up my resource loading by using a `CDN`. Is is possible to use a `CDN` other than one of Amazon's, since I am using `S3`? My hosting is from namecheap.com if that matters.

**Edit**

I guess my main question if whether what urls the content on where my CDN should point to... i.e.

`[ACCOUNT_NUM].[CDN_COMPANY].com` points to `cdn.[MYSITE].com`

or

`[ACCOUNT_NUM].[CDN_COMPANY].com` points to `[MY_S3_BUCKET].s3.amazonaws.com/`

or perhaps something else?

Comment: Not really programming related, that question. You should seek out another StackExchange site for that.

Comment: Have you considered adding a CloudFront distribution for your S3 bucket? That should give you a considerably faster delivery mechanism than serving those files directly from S3. It's also cheaper per request.

Comment: @Brandon - I do see that serving from S3 is slow, which is why I want  to use a CDN to mirror and server my existing S3 content. Obviously I'm sure Amazon services integrate better with each other than some other CDN, but I'd like to go with a service that allows me to pre-pay for a chunk of bandwidth.

Comment: Hmm. Well, FWIW, here's the CloudFront pricing model: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/ $0.12 for 10 TB of traffic from the U.S. is pretty cheap. How much bandwidth are you anticipating needing?

Comment: @Brandon didn't realize it was that cheap. Might end up going this route. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. CloudFront + S3 is hard to beat.